# Making a wrapper in HTML5 / CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a new website in HTML5 and CSS3.
I need to make some inner wrappers to center the content (960px wide).
I usually do this via something like

```
<style>
 .nav { height:40px; background:#000; }
 .wrapper { width:960px; margin:auto; }
</style>
<div class="nav">
 <div class="wrapper">
  Home News Blog etc etc
 </div>
</div>
```

However, I am new using the new HTML 5 elements such as header, nav, article etc and am wondering the best way to make a wrapper similar to above but in a better way?

Comment: Take a look here - http://html5boilerplate.com/  They utilizing some best practices out there

Comment: @Zoltan Thanks for your reply but that's not what I'm after. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe H5BP to be just another Moderizr which is no way related to my question.

Comment: Nope, it's not a single script or smth like that. It's basically a bunch of files to kick-start your development or prototyping. Usually you create the folders, index file, css files, js files, structure those - H5BP eliminates that step. So you have a basic website out of the box, with an `index.html` (if you scroll down and click on it you can see the markup), CSS reset/print/etc., some JS files included. Take a look at it ;-) It's exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually legal:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wrapping up HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header><h1>Using a HTML5 wrapper</h1></header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <hgroup>
            <h1>This is actually legal</h1>
            <h2>Just wrap everything in a div, just like before</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>But it's probably better to simply use the body tag.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer><p>Love from Kebman</p></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it is probably advicable to simply use `<body>` as a wrapper. After all, it's cleaner and adds less HTML.

Comment: Good, but what about those who want to use some "sticky" footer technique such as this: http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/P150/ ?

Comment: I just stick some CSS in, maybe something like this: `body{min-height:100%; position:relative;}` `footer{position:absolute; bottom:0;}` And then I make sure the section or article tag has a bottom padding of at least the heigth of the footer.

Comment: I think you forgot footer{min-width: 100%;} and I wouldn't put body{position:relative;} as it doesn't help push down the footer. However, I guess that in certain occasions the footer may have a strange behavior.

Comment: The width is up to you. `footer {position: absolute}` takes the footer element out of the element flow, while `body {position: relative}` forces the footer element back into the element flow as a child or branch of the body element. The technique is very useful for keeping child elements inside parent boundaries even after absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for alternative methods, you can also use the body

```
body{ margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, use a nav element for the nav, otherwise the div is fine for dividing it up.

Answer (score 0):

I still place everything in a wrapper div even using header, nav, footer, main as I find it easier to control complete content